# Prevent direct access to htm files, allow access through <frame> tags

Tags: .htaccess, html4

I'm working with an older web application that uses the HTML4 `<frame>` tag to insert the navbar, content etc. in the index.php file.

I want to allow the `<frame>` tag to load these files, but to prevent direct access to these .htm files.

It's not possible to change any of these .htm files as they are build automatically next time the application is updated with input. So it has to be done through .htaccess I assume.

I've tried to work with the following code, but this blocks the .htm files loading into the `<frame>` tag:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?domain [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(htm)$ - [F]
```

Frame tag section:

```
<frameset>
   <frame src="index.htm">
</frameset>
```

Comment: What referrer does your browser send, for the requests for the "framed" pages? Does it send one at all?

Comment: The browser doesn't send a referrer. I updated the question with the code where the frame is loaded.

Comment: _"The browser doesn't send a referrer."_ - so how did you expect this to work then? Your RewriteConds demand, that the referrer not be either of the two formats - and an "empty" referrer _does_ not match either of them. And in that case your RewriteRule now applies.

Comment: I was wrong about the referrer. The request is: GET /index.htm HTTP/1.1 with the referrer as the index.php file.

Comment: Then you should be able to test for (not) that one specific referrer, and without the need for any wildcards etc. no?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I changed the referrer to match the exact location of index.php and now it works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote the condition to check on to the referrer (index.php).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com/index.php$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(htm)$ - [F]
```

Thanks to CBroe for clearing my mind.